# "po-tay-to, po-tah-to" — як перекласти?

Tags: переклад, from-english

Як перекласти фразу *[po-tay-to, po-tah-to](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/potayto,_potahto)* українською мовою? Чи існує якийсь еквівалент для цієї фрази?

Ця фраза (а також аналогічна *[tomayto, tomahto](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/tomayto,_tomahto)*) вживається у значенні «байдуже, нема різниці, це те саме», наприклад от такі пояснення і приклад уживання [наводить](https://hinative.com/questions/13320307#answer-31965828) Kellyne на HiNative:

> It means that calling something by a different name doesn’t change what it is.
>
> *— Have fun at geek camp!
>
> — Excuse me, it’s Robotics camp.
>
> — Eh, po-tay-to po-tah-to. (Eh, same thing)*

Comment: Гадаю, що варто було б описати в чому суть цієї фрази інакше людям доводиться гуглити. А також, куди вам її треба вставити, бо якщо просто дві вимови одного і того ж слова, то таких багато.

Comment: Jakśćo treba pokazatı varijativnôstj, to: kartoplja, kartoflja, kartoxlja.

Comment: Особисто зустрічав фразу "що совою об пеньок[, що пеньком об сову]" у подібному сенсі. Хоча це ніби більше російське.

Answer (score 2):

На мою думку, завжди можна сказати буквально і нейтрально: *байдуже*, *нема різниці*, *однаково*, *це те саме*, *усе одно* тощо. (Щодо наголосу: я особисто конкретно в цьому значенні очікував би *ба́йдуже* (а *байду́же* в мене асоціюється рідше з загальним уживанням, як-от: вона байдуже дивилася у вікно). Але словники цієї різниці не наводять, згідно з ними обидва наголоси можливі (*ба́йду́же*) незалежно від контексту; імовірно, вони мають рацію.)

Також можна вжити якийсь зі стилістично забарвлених синонімів слова *байдуже* зі [«Словників України online»](https://lcorp.ulif.org.ua/dictua/), наприклад: *(на)плювати* і *(на)чхати*.

Також існує зовсім ненейтральна фраза *один хуй* і її евфемістичні варіанти *один хер* (іноді у варіанті *один хєр*), *один хрін*, *один фіг*. Можливо, вона має російське походження. Але на практиці очевидно вживається:

> Вареник: А шо там у тебе таке?
> Вєнік (тихо, зловісним голосом): Того ніхто не знає. <…> Одні кажуть, що там гестапо було, а старий Кіндрат <…> казав, шо тіатр… <…>
> Йонатан: Та… Шо тіатр, шо гестапо — один хуй (Лесь Подерв'янський, «Нірвана або Also Sprach Zarathustra», 1985(?)).
>
> — Ми тебе навіть у Мексиці знайшли б…
> — У Мексиці, — виправив ти його, — <…> за новим правописом має бути «у Мексиці»…
> — Та один хрін — хоч у Мексиці, хоч у Мексиці, однаково тобі гаплик! (Юрій Андрухович, «Московіада», 1992).
>
> — Відуху забрали так, студенти якісь забрели, молодята, їм один хер — бе-у, шме-у, аби фуричив (Андрій Кокотюха, «Мама, донька, бандюган», 2002).
>
> — <…> Так ти у нас психіатр! А? — захоплено каже Мишка.
> — Не психіатр, а психолог! — жартує Бідон.
> — Не один хєр! — продовжує Мишка (Анатолій Дністровий, «Місто уповільненої дії», 2002).
>
> — Він йому був як батько, — каже дядя Роберт.
> — Та ну, — раптом говорить Собака, — батько і вітчим — це зовсім різні речі. Хоча, — додає, — у принципі, один хуй (Сергій Жадан, «Депеш Мод», 2004).
>
> Собак не виявилося, проте виявилася клітка з кролями. Один фіг. Кролі, собаки. І тих і тих їдять (Артем Чех, «Doc 1», 2008).

Answer (score 1):

"Масло масляне – повторення одного й того ж іншими словами, які нічого не з'ясовують і не доповнюють".

src: http://korusno-znatu.in.ua/frazeologizmy/maslo-maslyane/

Comment: Тут ідеться про різну вимову. Це з американської пісні.

Comment: @Yola, хіба обов'язково про різну вимову? Я так розумію, це про те, що між якимись _поняттям А_ і _поняттям Б_ немає суттєвої різниці (типу, їх _порівнюють_ з різними вимовами). Хоча _масло масляне_ справді не те.

Comment: @Sasha здається таки про вимову. Вони [там](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LOILZ_D3aRg) саме про це сперечаються, а потім погоджуються на різницю.

Comment: @Yola, а бачили моє редагування до запитання? (Тобто я не заперечую, що оригінальна пісня саме про це, але я про сучасний вжиток вислову.)

Comment: йой, не помітив, тепер усе зрозуміло. Згоден з вами.